# if i get a new phone but same phone number, will i get the sent but undelivered messages people have sent me?

Tags: whatsapp.app

Im buying a new iphone and getting a number on it:

Here's the deal, i lost my phone and ever since then when somebody sends me messages it appears as sent but not delivered (only 1 check) now, if i get a new phone and start whatsapp on it with the same phone number, will i get those messages?

Those messages really matter and i would like to know if its worth doing all the process to get back the same number

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using the stock Messages app or Whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it hasn't been 30 days since you lost your phone, you will receive all pending messages. But if it has been more then 30 days, you will not receive those messages, as WhatsApp deletes them from their servers.

From WhatsApp's [FAQ:](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000050/?category=5245250)

> ...undelivered messages are deleted from our servers after 30 days.

On a side note, if it has been over two months since you lost the phone, then it's as if you're a new user on WhatsApp, and you will be removed from all of your WhatsApp groups.